# How to load a XIB with a top-level ViewController?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder, xib

I've got a nib with a view controller root element like this:

[image]

so I can position elements relative to the top and bottom layout guides using auto-layout.

When I first tried to load this nib using

```
SearchViewControllerPro* searchViewController = [[SearchViewControllerPro alloc]initWithNibName:@"SearchViewControllerPro" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
```

I got the following run-time exception:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIViewController
>   _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "SearchViewControllerPro" nib but the view outlet was not set.'

Googling the error it was pointed out to me, that the file owner of the xib needed to be set to the class of my view controller and the view outlet had to be set to the view object in the xib. If I do so, then I get the following run-time error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency', reason: 'A view can only be
>   associated with at most one view controller at a time! View > is associated with . Clear this association before associating this view with
>   .'

Does not come as a surprise since the view is associated to both the file owner and the top-level view controller of the nib. But how can I tell the run-time that they are both in fact the very same thing instead of two separate entities?

**Edit:**
When I try to unpck the ViewController from the nib like so,

```
NSArray* xibContents = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SearchViewControllerPro" owner:nil options:nil];
SearchViewControllerPro* mapSearchViewController = [xibContents lastObject];
```

, it does no good either:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException',
>   reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class
>   is not key value coding-compliant for the key view.

**Temporary solution:**

I found a solution, but it is not pretty. Despite the structure as shown in IB, the view controller is not the last object in the xib. So I have:

```
__block SearchViewControllerPro* mapSearchViewController = nil;
[xibContents enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    if ([obj isKindOfClass:[SearchViewControllerPro class]]) {
        mapSearchViewController = obj;
    }
}];
```

and this seems to work without run-time crashes. However, it's everything but clean code.

Comment: Regarding your edit.. you have errors in your nib. You need to make sure Class names are correct and you have to manually disconnect any incorrect connections you made. What have you set as the class of FilesOwner? What connections did you make to FilesOwner?

Comment: Ok it doesn't matter what you set the Class of FilesOwner to as long as you realise it will change depending on whether you do [NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:... or SearchViewControllerPro alloc]initWithNibName:... therefore any connections you have made to FilesOwner will be invalid (you will crash) if you change loading method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> how can I tell the run-time that they are both in fact the very same
>   thing instead of two separate entities?

You can't because they are not the same thing. You have created two `SearchViewControllerPro` intstances.

You need to either alloc-init a SearchViewControllerPro instance or unarchive one from a nib.

If you decide to create the ViewController in the nib the usual way to access it is the same way you would access any other item (view, button, textfield) that you create in a nib.

Add an outlet to the FilesOwner object, hook up the connection in interface builder and be sure to pass the object when you unarchive the nib.

eg If you want the Object that unarchives the nib to be FilesOwner:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SearchViewControllerPro" owner:self options:nil];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not sure I understand it though. I just tried to fetch the ``ViewController`` from inside the nib, but had no luck there (see my edit above, is that what you mean?). On your comment: Yes, I know that right now, I have two instances. What I meant to say is, I want resolve them into the same object and don't know how to do that in IB or code, since the alloc-initing fails (see errors above).

Comment: What would it mean to 'resolve two instances into the same object'? If i do: ob1 = [SearchViewControllerPro alloc] init]; ob2 = [SearchViewControllerPro alloc] init]; (and this is what you have done) How would i resolve them to one instance? Two objects is two objects.

Comment: Let me rephrase the question: I know how to load a nib as a view into a ``UIViewController``. Since for iOS7  I need to reposition elements relative to the topLayoutGuide, I had to put a view controller as top-level element in a nib, and my attempts to load it so far have failed. You are describing the symptom correctly - due to the structure of the nib and the way I tried to instantiate the view controller, I get two objects. But I don't know to set up the nib and the loading call so that I end up with only one. I hope that explains it better.

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer. Creating an outlet for an entire view controller is a neat trick. :-)

Comment: One remark for `[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:` - it calls `viewDidLoad` internally. So if we set some properties of view controller from code to use them in `viewDidLoad` method, we meet a problem...

Answer (score 3):

The following works as well and (at least to me) is a little more explicit that creating an outlet for the ViewController:

```
NSArray* xibContents = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SearchViewControllerPro" owner:nil options:nil];
SearchViewControllerPro* mapSearchViewController = [xibContents objectAtIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isIPad)
{
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ABC_iPad" owner:self
options:nil];

}
else{
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ABC_iPhone" owner:self options:nil];

}
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.