# presentViewController Warning view is not in the window hierarchy

Tags: ios

I am loading `LaunchViewController` as the root view controller in my AppDelegate's `application:didFinishLaunching` method:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"LaunchViewController" bundle:nil];
    LaunchViewController *launchViewController = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
    launchViewController.managedObjectContext = [CurrentSession mainQueueContext];
    self.window.rootViewController = launchViewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

LaunchViewController communicates with a web server to fetch some data. I am using AFNetworking library for asynchronous communication with the web server. In the success callback after fetching the data, I am presenting the LoginViewController. My understanding is that the callbacks in case of AFNetworking are performed on the main thread. Nevertheless I used `performSelectionOnMainThread` just to see if that would resolve the issue:

Inside callback:

```
 [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(presentLoginView) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

`presentLoginView`method:

```
- (void)presentLoginView {
    LoginViewController *loginViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil];
    loginViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    [self presentViewController:loginViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

The login view is not presented and in the console I see following message:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <LoginViewController: 0x78e47c30> on <LaunchViewController: 0x78eb4a60> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

:-(

**UPDATE**
I put a breakpoint in viewDidLoad, viewDidUnload, viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear methods of the LoginViewController. viewDidLoad was hit. Others were not.
Why would the view get loaded but not appear?

Comment: I got the same problem, but I just ignore it and it still works as it should.

Comment: Oh. I wonder then what is going on in my case because the Login View is not being presented. I did rename the xib file of my LoginViewController earlier. And in the code I am using the new xib name and I have made sure that the new xib name is in the target build phase. Don't know what else to do. Bummed.

Comment: May I ask why you work with .xibs?

Comment: It is an old codebase.

Comment: Oh ok, well I can't help you but I'll wait until someone else does :D

Comment: Btw, I put a breakpoint in `viewDidLoad`, `viewDidUnload`, `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` methods of the LoginViewController. `viewDidLoad` was hit. Others were not.

Comment: @gagarwal, that is not necessary, and you shouldn't do it. Adding the controller as the rootViewController adds the view for you.

Comment: @septerr: Where is `[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(presentLoginView) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];` getting called? When and how do you start the fetch via AFNetworking?

Comment: AppDelegate loads LaunchViewController as root view controller. When LaunchViewController is presented, there is a button on it called Launch. The target action for this button is a method that makes AFNetworking call. In AFN's success callback, `[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(presentLoginView) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];` is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my AFNetworking success callback I was setting some of the information obtained from the web server into NSUserDefaults. And then I was presenting the LoginViewController.

My AppDelegate was listening to `NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification` notification. The handler for this notification would set the launchViewController as the root view controller.

So, in the AFNetworking callback while I was asking LaunchViewController to present LoginViewController I was also sending off NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification which would cause the AppDelegate to load the LaunchViewController.

I never saw even a flicker of LoginViewController ever. So, I think the AppDelegate handler was getting fired first and then the presentLoginViewController was getting called. And this somehow lead to the views not being added to window hierarchy message.

Answer (score 0):

That's probably happening because the AFNetworking execute the callback very fast, for instance before the view of the view controller is loaded, maybe because you are using a local server or another configuration in viewDidLoad that is slow. In this case I would recommend to move the code to viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear since in that moment the view would be in the hierarchy and therefore you would be able to present another ViewController from there.

Comment: The loading of data via AFNetworking is triggered when the user hits a button in LauncViewController's view. So this happens well after the LaunchViewController's view has been loaded and shown.

Comment: In that case maybe it has something to do with the fact that you renamed your xib file. Try checking this other question about how to load nibs and the role of the owner. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19001808/how-to-load-a-xib-with-a-top-level-viewcontroller

Comment: I reverted the xib rename. Made sure the old xib had the correct file owner and was in the build phase resources. Changed code to use the old nib name. And getting same behavior.